# React JS, display Data from Nested json

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble displaying data from this nested json
I can't display all items in the items box
I've tried some solution but still not work,
since my json format is kinda different.

Json data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "pattern": "Right",
      "Color": "blue",
      "Weight": "50",
      "items": {
        "chair": {
          "location": "c1-2a",
          "quantity": "10",
          "available": true
        },
        "table": {
          "location": "c1-2c",
          "quantity": "5",
          "available": false
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "pattern": "Left",
      "Color": "green",
      "Weight": "12",
      "items": {
        "mouse": {
          "location": "c2-2a",
          "quantity": "29",
          "available": true
        },
        "headphones": {
          "location": "c1-2e",
          "quantity": "50",
          "available": false
        },
        "monitor": {
          "location": "c1-2e",
          "quantity": "2",
          "available": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

React Code

```
class UsersTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            data: []

        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/test")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        data: result.data
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }


    render() {

        const {error, isLoaded, data} = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return (
                <table id="example" className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pattern</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>item</th>
                        <th>location</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    {data.map(item =>
                        (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{item.pattern}</td>
                                    <td>{item.color}</td>
                                    <td>{item.items}</td> <======= I cant loop all items
                                    <td>{item.location}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ))}

                    </tbody>
                </table>


            );
        }
    }

}
```

Expected result

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|Patern|Color |    Item                |Location         |  
----------------------------------------------------------
|Right |blue  |chair,table             |c1-2a,c1-2c      |
|left  |green |mouse,headphones,monitor|c2-2a,c1-2e,c1-2e|
```

Error result

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child `(found: object with keys {chair, table})`. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You trying to loop over an object, use `[key, value] of Object.entries`

---

```
  <td>{for let [key, value] of Object.entries(item.items) { ....  }</td>
```

Comment: It seems, not the case since I can access other key, except from items which have key=>value under it

Comment: Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`));
This works displays all items, i might just need to format it properly,

Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

items is a object in your case, first you have extract values from items object by using items.map() or so. Because items is a object hence you are getting below error.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {chair, table}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: hi, could you help give example, 
I tried and items is not found
```
<td>{items.map(it => (
                                        {it}
                                    ))}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before returing from map fuction, first map over items and create string of items object.

```
{data.map(item => {
      var items = item.items;
      var itemList = "";
      items.forEach(item => {
          itemList = itemList + item + " ,"; 
     })
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <tr>
               <td>{item.pattern}</td>
               <td>{item.color}</td>
               <td>{itemList}</td>
               <td>{item.location}</td>
            </tr>
         </React.Fragment>
   )))}
```

Comment: I can't seem to make this work since it almost changes the type of my code(im following tutorials)

Comment: Which tutorial you are following?